# Eclipse 3.5 and Ubuntu 9.10, subversion client does not work

Tags: eclipse, svn, ubuntu

I had installed Eclipse 3.5 Yoxos on my Ubuntu 8.04 for month, and run fine. I had upgraded to 9.10 last week, and the subversion plugin does not work since upgrade.
When I try to update or commit, Subversion work for hours without any progress in console or progress bars. I can delete files or add them to SVN, but commands wich involve network just hang.

SVN run fine using command line.
I have already patched the GDK problem. Since this I can cancel update/commit without crashing Eclipse.

Regards
Cédric

addedum: here is the error showed in the Eclipse console after severals minutes. On the same directory the command line run fine.

```
*** Update
svn update "/home/cedric/www/VOO123" -r HEAD --depth infinity
svn: timed out waiting for server
svn: OPTIONS request failed on '/VOO123/trunk'
*** Error (took 10:43.893)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved : Eclipse have problems under Ubuntu Karmic (9.10), you have to inactivate Assistive Technologies to sold them (a cash in libpango), and since I had inactivated them and restarted my session, it just fine, SVN included.

Answer (score 1):

It might be related to the IPV6_V6ONLY setting - I know that this can be a problem for some Java apps on Debian.

Take a look in `/etc/sysctl.d/bindv6only.conf` and look for a line starting with `net.ipv6.bindv6only`. If it isn't already, set it to 0:

```
 net.ipv6.bindv6only = 0
```

Comment: there is no such file on my ubuntu box, so I put this line in /etc/sysctl.conf before rebooting, but nothing change.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say since you don't even mention which plugin you're using but if I remember well, I was using Subclipse with the SVNKit Client Adapter successfully on Ubuntu 9.10 (I use Subclipse with the JavaHL (JNI) library again on Ubuntu 10.04).

Comment: I have plugins subversion, subversive svn connectors/team provider and svnkit 1.3.0. I try to re-install all including subclipse but it did not help.